# StreamReader to Array 2d C#

Tags: c#

I am new into C# and I'm trying to use StreamReader to read a txt file and insert it into an array 2d. I know it should've been done on a generic list, but this is meant to be on a matrix.

I know it's something basic but why the code isn't reading the file? I mean the code is executed but when I check on the matrix if the data was insert, the matrix remains empty. My concern is why is StreamReader not importing files?

Thank you for looking into the code, sorry if it's something basic.

```
 static void importRecordMethod(string[,] matrix)
    {
        string file = "../archives/Export.txt";

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                            {
                                {
                                    matrix[i, j] = line;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the outcome of `File.Exists(file)`?

Comment: Your code writes every line on each position of your array. Everything is overwritten by the last line. Perhaps the last line is empty in your file, hence your array is empty.

Comment: Awful way to serialize matrix data by the way. Are the values really strings?

Comment: You are using sr.ReadLine() which is giving you an array of characters, not splitting the line by fields (columns).  You need to split line by separator or fixed column widths.

Comment: they are string values. I have a method to export data to Txt files and I wanted the opposite, to read the file and insert data into the matrix. However the code is executed but the matrix doesn't have anything inserted

Comment: Have you considered debugging your code in a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you quickly try this:

```
static void importRecordMethod(string[,] matrix)
    {
        string file = "../archives/Export.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(file))
            return;
        try
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        string line;
                        if ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Loop index {j + matrix.GetLength(0) * i}, Line: {line}");
                            matrix[i, j] = line;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // check if matrix is empty
                for (var i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(matrix[i, j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

After the execution I run this method to make sure if it was inserted or not:

```
  static void list<T>(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int x = matrix.GetUpperBound(1), width = (tableWidth / x);

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j]?.Trim();


                        if (matrix[i, j]?.Length > width)
                        {
                            Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j].Substring(0, width - 2) + ".." + "|"}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]?.PadRight(width - (width - matrix[i, j].Length) / 2)?.PadLeft(width)}|");
                        }


                }
                 Console.WriteLine(); 
            }

        }
```

Comment: the matrix remais the same, I mean the method is executed, it does not go to the catch statement, however when I run a nested for the visualize what's inside the matrix, the data wasn't inserted on it

Comment: And what is the console output?

Comment: Did you debug it step by step? did you check if the line are read correctly?

Comment: The output is correct I'm getting the values from the txt into the line.        
                  Loop index 0, Line: 1;richard;Street nº1;USA;12345-120;10/10/1992;M;912034890;12453207;true;
Loop index 1,                 Line: 2;Mary;USa;Oregon;124586;10/02/1990;F;14552;1234566+;true;
Loop index 3, Line:

Comment: OK. The matrix isn't empty. Why do you think it is? "I run a nested for the visualize what's inside the matrix, the data wasn't inserted on it" - **I have no idea what you mean.**

Comment: @ricardo: See updated answer. Please test it and check the console output.

Comment: @ricardo You are testing it with very complicated code. Just print the matrix as I suggested. Is it empty?

Comment: Then I cannot help any further I'm afraid. I created a file from your output, ran my code and it worked. You need now to debug carefully line by line. 
Also your `list<T>` does not need the generic `T` parameter.

Comment: @ricardo: I created a .netfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cknzuV It saves four example lines into a file and then starts executing your code. It works. It is not empty. (I had to adjust your code a little bit, to get it compiled.)

Comment: thank you the generic T was there because I was using an enum as a Header, thanks for the code as well, I'll do bebug as you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Ok, you read line by line whole file, and then for every line

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        {
            matrix[i, j] = line;
        }
    }
}
```

you fill whole matrix with that line.

So, whole matrix became re-initialized with every line, and as result it has the latest line for every cell.

As it is "empty" as you say, that means that last line of file is empty.